# ReactJS: render private route if authenticated after promise resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

i have this `PrivateRoute` functional component which decides to render component which passed as props for the user which he has access to based upon his authentication or redirect to unauthorised route.

`isValidToken` is a **async function** checks if user has valid token or not and returns a **boolean** which is assigned to `isUserLogged` .so when i called this function in `useEffect` hook its waits for the function to resolve but before its finishing the redirecting happens . so how i await till it resolves and render based upon that value before the promise resolves ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import isValidToken from "../utils/isValidToken";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Comp, path, redirectto, ...rest }) => {
  const [isloggedin, setloggedin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      const isUserLogged = await isValidToken();
      setloggedin(isUserLogged);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return isloggedin ? (
          <Comp {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={redirectto} />
          // <h1>404 error</h1>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid the premature redirect, your component needs to account for the "pending state" of the promise (that's behind your async function call).

During the pending (or "loading") state, you'll typically render something like a loading spinner to indicate to the user that the app is busy. The key is to not render the `<Comp />` or `<Redirect />` component until the promise is resolved (or rejected):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import isValidToken from "../utils/isValidToken";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Comp, path, redirectto, ...rest }) => {

  /* Track the state of your app instead. Start with a "loading" state */
  const [state, setState] = useState('loading');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      try {
        /* Update effect logic to track correct state */
        const isUserLogged = await isValidToken();
        setState(isUserLogged ? 'loggedin' : 'redirect');
      }
      catch {
        setState('redirect');
      }
    })();
  }, []);
  
  /* If in loading state, return loading message while waiting for 
  isValidToken to complete */
  if(state === 'loading') {
    return <div>Loading..</div>
  }

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      {/* Decide what component to render based on state */
      render={props => ((state === 'loggedin') ? 
        <Comp {...props} /> : 
        <Redirect to={redirectto} />) }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import isValidToken from "../utils/isValidToken";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Comp, path, redirectto, ...rest }) => {
  const [isloggedin, setloggedin] = useState(false);

  const [redirectTo, setRedirectTo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      const isUserLogged = await isValidToken();
      setloggedin(isUserLogged);
      setRedirectTo('/route');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (redirectTo && isloggedin) {
      return <Redirect to={redirectTo} />
  }

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={props => <Comp {...props} />}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```